# How to post a message for p:growl only

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

On a successful action method a ViewScoped bean is posting an INFO message and then it returns a navigation string. The target page is showing the message on a p:messages and a p:growl instances. No problem so far. However this page displays a list of many records on a p:datatable with lazy loading and a paginator. Now, if I paginate to other set of records the p:messages still is showing the posted message. I want to show the posted message only on the p:growl which would disappear after a few seconds, while p:messages keeps showing it forever.
This doesn't work for me, according to the official documentation:

```
<p:growl for="anotherkey" />
context.addMessage("anotherkey", facesMessage3);
```

any help would be very appreciated. (PF 6.1, JSF 2.2, Omnifaces 2.5, PrettyFaces 3.3.3 on Tomee+MySql)

Comment: I found a partial solution: just added a p:ajax to the datatable. However, the growl is not showing the message any more. With the the ajax event if I paginate to another set of records the p:messages disappear as I wished. Still remains unsolved 'how to send a message to p:growl only'

Comment: <p:ajax event="page" update="messages growl" />